# Macintosh and powerpc tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

To designate Macintosh hardware, we now have a [macbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook) and [macbookpro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro). I don't think `macbookpro` should be a separate tag.

There's a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/perfect-distro-for-an-old-mac-desktop-ppc-g3-320mb-ram) which is about a non-macbook Mac. Is [macintosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh) the right tag? Or [powerpc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerpc)? or both?

Should [macbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook) be made a synonym of [macintosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh), or is there really a need for different tags?

---

Given the response, please synonym:

- [ppc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ppc) → [powerpc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerpc) (already done)
- [macbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook) → [macintosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh)
- just kill [macbookpro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) (its questions already have [macbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook) as well)

Comment: why not just simply "mac"?

Comment: @Jeff: Possible confusion with MAC address. Given the respective popularity of Macintosh vs MAC address, even amongst the Unix.SE audience, this may not matter.

Comment: "apple" or "apple-mac" then? "macbook" is a horrendous tag.

Comment: This will change everything. Again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have one single tag, use [macintosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh).

If you want to split the questions into two groups, there are several ways Macs can be divided. For example:

- **Portability**

  - [mac-desktop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-desktop)
    Mac Pro, iMac, mini, Xserve, PowerMac, Cube
  - [mac-laptop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-laptop)
    MacBook, MacBook Pro, iBook, PowerBook
- **Era**

  - [mac-ppc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-ppc)
    PowerMac, PowerBook, iBook, Cube, iMac (some)
  - [mac-intel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-intel)
    Mac Pro, mini, Xserve, MacBook, MacBook Pro, iMac (some)

  ***or***

  - [mac-obsolete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-obsolete)
    PowerMac, PowerBook, iBook, Cube, PPC-based iMac, 68020, 68030, 68040
  - [mac-current](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-current)
    Mac Pro, mini, Xserve, MacBook, MacBook Pro, Intel-based iMac

And of course, there are bound to be questions about Linux on devices that ship with iOS (iPhone, iPad, Apple TV), so you might want to keep those in mind, too.

Comment: Very good point about the iDevices. I don't think we'll need to distinguish between the various types of Mac, the questions that require that tend to be asked at AD.

Comment: The last is no good, since today's current is tomorrow's obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

PowerPC is an architecture like x86 or x86_64. Modern Mac's run on Intel and are not PowerPC. Also PowerPC was an IBM architecture, and I don't think apple was the only hardware that had it (I might be wrong). So `/macbook` should not be a synonym of `/macintosh` and neither should `/powerpc`. As far as `/macbook` and `/macbookpro` they are probably completely unnecessary, I would think the underlying architecture to be more interesting, this is like tagging `/dell`, `/latitude` or `/dell`, `/inspiron` I really doubt those last 2 tags are remotely relevant `/dell`, `/laptop` maybe.

Comment: I agree. Having `/macbook` and `/macbookpro` is superfluous. It's interesting though. I'd probably be in favour of `/macintosh` & `/laptop`, although you're burning a tag option there and are only left with three more. I don't think there's any use in having `/ppc` and `/powerpc` either. I'd opt for just `/ppc` as that's how it's generally referred to in .iso names from what I've seen.

Comment: @boehj: `ppc`/`powerpc` is about the processor architecture, and it's distinct from Mac. There are non-PPC (vintage m68k, or modern intel) Macs, and there are a few non-Mac PPC (embedded or supercomputer).

Comment: @xenoterracide: Since people are spontaneously using `macbook`, I think it should be left, but it should redirect to a more general tag (`macintosh`?).

Comment: @Gilles - I realize it's an arch, but I'd still favour just `/ppc`. I'm not sure, but do we have `/AMD64` + `/x86_64` tags? If we do, I view this as superfluous in the same way, preferring to use just one, however controversial.

Comment: @gilles maybe it should. amd64 maybe be a tag synonym for x86_64 ... it depends on how people are using it... whether they are referring to the architecture or a processor.

Comment: @xenoterracide: We have neither, people have been using `64bit`. `amd64` and `x86_64` are exact synonyms, it's not like ppc/mac, they're both processor types.

Comment: @gilles oh I'm thinking athlon64

Answer (score -1):

I'm kind of inclinded towards something like "apple-hardware"....

Comment: I don't really like artificially introducing a tag that no one spontaneously uses.

Comment: And more to the point, questions about connecting to an iDevice or running on an iDevice are also apple-hardware but we don't want to gather them in a single tag. I hadn't even thought of this before Dori's post.

Comment: Yeah, good point on the idevices.