# Merge tags mac and macintosh

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can the tag [mac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) be made a synonym of [macintosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh)?

There is another discussion [here about mac related tags](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/606/1925), but it doesn't deal with the [mac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac), only with variant issues like [powerpc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerpc) and [macbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
updating post history, 3 rows affected
updating posts, 1 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 1 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [macintosh] and [mac] complete!
Tag Synonym mac -> macintosh was approved!
```